# Row over partition for totaling data by month

Tags: sql, t-sql, window-functions

I have some data that I need to sum for each month and I am having trouble figuring out how to get it to have 12 columns (one for each month) with the sum total for that month.

Example:

Data as is:

```
GrossAmt    ClaimDate
49764.00    2014-08-21 00:00:00.000
1382.43     2014-08-27 00:00:00.000
602.77      2014-09-02 00:00:00.000
497.04      2014-09-02 00:00:00.000
```

desired result:

```
GrossAmt    ClaimDate
51146.43    August
1099.81     September
```

actual Desired Result:

```
July  August    September
0     51146.43  1099.81
```

Sorry I did not include this before!

I am sure that this is the most basic example of using row over partition perhaps it is my lack of programming background but this is one concepts that I just can not wrap my head around.

This is what I have so far but I am not sure where to go next.

```
With CTE ([GrossAmt],ClaimMonth)
AS(
SELECT TOP 10000 
       Sum([GrossAmt]) as TotalClaimAmt
      ,CASE WHEN Month([ClaimDate]) = 1 THEN 'January'
            WHEN Month([ClaimDate]) = 2 THEN 'February'
            WHEN Month([ClaimDate]) = 3 THEN 'March'
            WHEN Month([ClaimDate]) = 4 THEN 'April'
            WHEN Month([ClaimDate]) = 5 THEN 'May'
            WHEN Month([ClaimDate]) = 6 THEN 'June'
            WHEN Month([ClaimDate]) = 7 THEN 'July'
            WHEN Month([ClaimDate]) = 8 THEN 'August'
            WHEN Month([ClaimDate]) = 9 THEN 'September'
            WHEN Month([ClaimDate]) = 10 THEN 'October'
            WHEN Month([ClaimDate]) = 11 THEN 'November'
            WHEN Month([ClaimDate]) = 12 THEN 'Decmber'
        End  AS ClaimMonth
  FROM [Database].[dbo].[Table]
    )
    Group BY  [ClaimDate]
    )
  Select * From CTE
```

Perhaps what I might need is a basic lesson on how Row over partition works.  I have tried reading articles I have found online but none seem to make sense to me, They are way to advanced and I get lost right away, Also it does not help that I do not learn very well by reading, I need to see it in action, and understand how it works.

Anyway, thanks for the help.  You guys rock!
EDIT:

actual Desired Result:

```
July  August    September
0     51146.43  1099.81
```

Sorry I did not include this before!

Comment: You could use `DATENAME(MONTH,[ClaimDate])` instead of that awkard `CASE` expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `PIVOT` to get the desired results

CTE is doing the Monthly aggregation and PIVOT is used to convert the CTE result rows into horizontal columns

```
;With CTE ([GrossAmt],MonthVal)
AS(
SELECT TOP 10000 
       Sum([GrossAmt]) as GrossAmt,
       DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,ClaimDate), 0) as MonthVal
  FROM [Table1]
  Group BY  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,ClaimDate), 0)
)
SELECT * FROM
(Select [GrossAmt], DATENAME(MONTH,MonthVal) as ClaimMonth From CTE) t
PIVOT
( MAX(GrossAmt) for ClaimMonth  in 
  ( [January], [Febrauary], [March], [April], [May], [June], [July],  
    [August],  [September], [October], [November], [December] 

  )
)pvt
```

Comment: 2 Great answers, but you gave a great explanation as well.  Thank you for the explanation.  It makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @Cols =  STUFF((
                SELECT DISTINCT ', ' +  QUOTENAME(DATENAME(MONTH,ClaimDate))
                FROM TABLENAME
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'')
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql  = 'SELECT ''GrossAmount'' AS AMOUNT_Sorted_By_DATE, 
' + @Cols +   '
FROM
(SELECT [GrossAmt], DATENAME(MONTH,ClaimDate) as ClaimMonth
FROM TABLENAME GROUP BY MONTH(ClaimDate)) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
SUM(GrossAmt)
FOR DATENAME(MONTH,ClaimDate) IN (' + @Cols +   ')
) AS PivotTable'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
```

This will result in Only the number of Months Actually Having data.

Answer (score -1):

```
With CTE ([GrossAmt],ClaimMonth)
AS(
SELECT TOP 10000 
       Sum([GrossAmt]) as TotalClaimAmt
      ,DATENAME(MONTH, ClaimDate) AS ClaimMonth
  FROM [Database].[dbo].[Table]
  Group BY  DATENAME(MONTH, ClaimDate)
)
Select * From CTE
```

Comment: I screwed up my desired results.  My fault. I am actually looking for this:

actual Desired Result:

    July  August    September
    0     51146.43  1099.81

Answer (score -1):

```
select top 1000 
       datename(month, [ClaimDate]), SUM([GrossAmt]) 
  from [Table] 
 group by datename(month, [ClaimDate])
```

Comment: I did not downvote you but the only thing I can think of is that this answers my original question perfectly, but I posted an edit that basically changed the entire question. You answered the first one.  My fault. But yours is right on for what I initially posted.